# Question about “making focus on”

Tags: expressions

I just made these sentences. Are they okay especially in speaking?

Ex) He explained information making focus on food section.

Ex) Please explain it making focus on fundamental principle.

Ex) She did shopping making focus on clothes.

Ex) He did workout making focus on abs.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase

> **making focus on**

is usually said as

> **focusing on**

So, your sentences might be

> He explained **the** information **focusing** on **the** food section.
>
> Please explain it **focusing** on **the** fundamental principle.

***"The"*** is added since there is only *one* section and *one* principle.

For your setences in the *past*.

> She did **her** shopping **focusing** on clothes.
>   She **shopped focusing** on clothes.
>   She **focused** on **her** clothes shopping.
>
> He did **his** workout **focusing** on *(his)* abs.
>   He **workedout focusing** on *(his)* abs.
>   His workout **focused** on **his** abs.